# Advantages of "class SimpleComponent extends Component{}" towards "React.createClass()"

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React.JS and trying to figure out what the advantages of the newer approach with "class SimpleComponent extends Component{}" towards "React.createClass()" is. Would be great if someone can explain me that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because React.createClass({...}) is [deprecated as of April 2017](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.createclass).

> When React was initially released, there was no idiomatic way to
>   create classes in JavaScript, so we provided our own:
>   React.createClass.
>
> Later, classes were added to the language as part of ES2015, so we
>   added the ability to create React components using JavaScript classes.
>   Along with functional components, JavaScript classes are now the
>   preferred way to create components in React.